# How should I position this text over my image?

Tags: html, css

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkI6X.jpg) is what I am trying to recreate.

This is what I have so far for HTML:

```css
.carousel-cell {
  position: relative;
}

.board-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-cell">
  <img src="img/board1.png" alt="">
  <div class="board-text">
    <h4>Funboards</h4>
    <h2>Chilli Rare Bird</h2>
    <h3>$890</h3>
    <p>Buy</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you set left property to .board-text? Say maybe 50-60% depending on what you're trying to achieve... Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/6d83osg5/

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to place text over an `<img>` but you can create a box and then give the box the image as a `background-image`. Then you can write the text you want in the box. 
HTML example: `<div id="imageBox">Your text</div>`
CSS: `#imageBox{background-image: url(img/board1.jpg)}`
Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Absolute positioning with CSS, SVG, server side rendering of the image to dynamically place text on top... There are plenty of ways to place text over an image.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this

```
.carousel-cell {
  position: relative;
}
.carousel-cell img{
  width:600px;
}
.board-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform:translate(0,-50%);
  left:420px;
}
```